# jQuery - When class is removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, events

I've a div with this class `Loading` .. I just need to do something in jQuery when this class is removed.

I have try this

```js
$(".class").not('loading').each(function(){

  // do something

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: why not write your codes along with the "remove" class codes?

Comment: How do you remove  the class `.loading`?

Comment: `I just need to do something in jQuery when this class is removed.` which event triggers removal of class?

Comment: You need to catch an event. Basically, when is the class removed?

Comment: It's removing automatically

Comment: I guess "Automatically" is not the valid response here. I presume automatically again means by some JS/JQuery Events or CSS (Like: Hover, Click, Load, document.ready, etc...).

Comment: And if you are not using any event, you should know that the class is removed just after the code that automatically remove the classes.

Comment: It's removing after some JSON scripts loading completely

Comment: Then you have to use your code (don't forget to add a dot to the class inside `.not()` method) after those JSON scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have already removed the class and trying to do this.

```
$(".class").not('.loading').each(function(){
  // do something
});
```

Otherwise,

```
if(!$('.class').hasClass('loading')){
//Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your comments i assume that your `.loading` class is removed **on document ready**.

So try this following code make sure to wrap it in `$(document).ready(function(){..........});`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".demo").removeClass("loading"); // Remove this line and check again you will understand the difference

  if(!$(".demo").hasClass("loading"))
  {
   alert("Loading Class is Removed!");
  }  
});
```

```css
.demo
{
  color:green;
}

.loading
{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demo loading">
  This is loading class
</div>
```

> **Note:** Here where i am using `alert` you must add your script of what you want to do, or make happen on remove of class `.loading`.

[Working : JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/o67zk4z6/)